# Convert a double byte character into a single byte character in shell

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to convert a double byte character into a single byte character in shell script.

Input: １ＭＯＲＥ , ３６０ＦＬＹ , ＢＣジャパン , デイテル・ジャパン

Output: 1MORE , 360FLY ,BCジャパン , デイテル・ジャパン

Comment: Hi, please start over there https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and feel free to edit question afterwards. You can improve eg. missing example and expected output. Thanks

Comment: Edited. Please check

Comment: Not an expert on the matter, but I think those are 4-byte characters... An my first knee-jerk reaction would be to say "Yes, as long as you don't mind that it is no longer meaningful in any reliable way."

Comment: Nope. They are 3-byte chars, precisely because they need more info than an ASCII or utf-8 could provide to differentiate them all. Reducing them to single-byte characters is the idealogical equivalent of assigning random numbers from 1-100 into a single digit.